# How to open page by clicking on image in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

In my React project I've certain cards created which has images on it. When clicked on that image, its expected to open details of that particular product in new window/page, but, this doesn't happen.
Please see the code below.

Projects.js

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/details/${data.id}`}}>
          <MDBCardImage className="img-fluid" src={data.img}
          waves style={{borderRadius:'10px'}} 
          style={{height:'300px', width:'310px'}}
          />
</Link>
```

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
     <Switch>
       <Route path="/details/:id" component={Details}/>
     </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Is this the right way or I've to do some changes.Any solution?

Comment: can you share your code in sandbox?

Comment: do you mean on new tab ?

Comment: Where do you use your `Link`? Can we see the whole component and related components?

Comment: @devserkan yes I will edit the post

Comment: I will also show my code on sandbox

Comment: @devserkan please see my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/portfolio-vq88f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your improved code in sandbox.

[Improved your code in sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/portfolio-svn45)

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <TransitionGroup>
      <CSSTransition timeout={280} classNames="fade">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
            <Route path="/details/:id" exact component={Details} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </CSSTransition>
    </TransitionGroup>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js

```
return (
      <div>
        <Layout fixedHeader>
          <div className="menu">
            <a href="/">
              <span>Home</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#section_1">
              <span>Projects</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </Layout>
        <Content style={{ width: "100%" }}>
          <Projects />
        </Content>
      </div>
    );
```

Projects.js

```
  <Link to={{ pathname: `/details/${data.id}`, data: data }}>
       <MDBCardImage
        className="img-fluid"
        src={data.img}
        style={{
        height: "300px",
        width: "310px",
        borderRadius: "10px"
        }}
        />
   </Link>
```

Details.js

```
render() {
    const { data } = this.props.location;
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
        <h3>{data.title}</h3>
        <img src={data.img} alt="git-icon" style={{ height: "200px" }} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: When clicked on image it must redirect to details page defined in App.js

Comment: @Pranav please share in sandbox

Comment: @Pranav are you having like this?

Comment: this is my codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/portfolio-vq88f

Comment: Hey thanks man... Perfect Answer as expected... You have almost done all my work

Comment: One small mistake occurring... when Details page is refreshed it gives error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined'. Why this must be happening? Any idea

Comment: @Pranav i passed data just to show, you fetch particular detail data by id in details page.

Answer (score 1):

As we can see in your sandbox you are rendering the details page actually but below the projects. Your `Projects` component is above your `BrowserRouter` So, you are rendering the projects no matter what and this is why you see it always on every page. You don't have the main route right now, so you can use `Projects` if you want it in that way. Remove the `Projects` which is out of the router and put it as the main route component. Also, you need `exact` prop there.

```
<Content style={{ width: "100%" }}>
  <TransitionGroup>
    <CSSTransition timeout={280} classNames="fade">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Projects} /> 
          <Route path="/details/:id" component={Details} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </CSSTransition>
  </TransitionGroup>
</Content>
```